# "zsh:1: command not found: git" Emacs App on MacOS

Tags: osx, environment

My Emacs App used to work fine until today, it starts to complain that `zsh:1: command not found: git`

`git` is installed on my computer at `/usr/bin/git`

Other info:

- MacOS: Monterey
- Emacs: 27.2

[image: a screen shot of the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also complains about not finding `tr`.  I suspect that you've changed your `PATH` environment variable to something invalid such that it doesn't contain `/usr/bin` anymore.

Comment: Yes, I added the following to `init.el`: ```(setenv "PATH" (concat ":/usr/bin/" (getenv "PATH")))
 (add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/bin/")```

Comment: @xiaohan2012 That is wrong you need the : after /usr/bin ie "/usr/bin:" Look at what exec-path is. ALso I can't see why you are adding /usr/bin to the PATH in the first place as that will already be on the path.